# How to run a function on every page in ZF2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I'm new to ZEND so go easy, I have a menu table set up in mysql called menu_table, how do I run a function on every page to select * from that table and then pass it through to Module/Application/View/layout/layout.phtml

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in this case would be to create **custom View Helper** to get all menu items from the menu_table.

- In custom View Helper you have to inject service or mapper with method to get all data
- Custom View Helper should call from layout.phtml